# Laravel: Display data using drop down list

Tags: laravel

I am implementing a drop down menu list to display a list of hotels from my system. I currently have the following code which when i click submit, nothing is happening (no data displayed).

Does anyone know how i can potentially display data once i press submit. I do believe i need code in my controller.

> SEARCH.BLADE.PHP

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">
 @foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->distance}}">{{$post->distance}} </option>
 @endforeach

   <br/>
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="state" id="state" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="city">
    </select>
   </div>
   <br />
   <div class="form-group">
    <select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">
    @foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->title}}">{{$post->title}} </option>
 @endforeach
</div>
    </select>
   </div>
  </div>
  {{Form::Submit('submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])}}
 </body>
```

> SearchController.php

```
class SearchController extends Controller { 
   public function index()
   {
     $posts = Post::all();
     return view('Pages.search')->with('posts', $posts);
   }
```

I do not have much is the search controller but i do believe i need some code in there to display the data.

Comment: close your `<select>` tag with `</select>`, and debug `$posts` to insure in has data from database

Comment: You need to pass data to Controller Function and write a query for search ,close you select tag and form

Comment: i removed the select tag in this instance as it was too much code. Are you able to write code of what it should be in the controller ?

Comment: you need to close your `</select>` tags. also you can clean up your controller code with using compact `return view('Pages.search', compact('posts'));`

Comment: `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-adminsqure pull-right submitbutton"> Submit</button>`

Comment: but how would i display the data from the submit button ?

Comment: which data you want to show on your form? which is selected from dropdown? I can see that your form is submitted and redirected to `/search` path is there anything defined on that path?

Comment: @prateikDarji Exactly, so i want to return the data that is selected from the dropdown. The search path is the page that contains the drop down list, however when i click submit it takes me to a blank white page. Im not sure what to add to the controller to make this work

Comment: you should have to define route in routes.php file for search page, then method in controller for redirection on proper page. check for error log in storage/logs and share the details what errors are you getting

Comment: i have routes etc defined, do i need a function in my controller for search

Comment: yes and that function should have all the filters which needs to apply on data and redirect/load proper view, I think whole functionality needs to be perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use this**

```
<form action="/search" method="POST" role="search">

<div class="form-group">

<select name="country" id="country" class="form-control input-lg dynamic" data-dependent="state">

@foreach($posts as $post)
   <option value="{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}} </option>
@endforeach

</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

<select name="city" id="city" class="form-control input-lg">

@foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}} </option>
@endforeach

</select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-adminsqure pull-right submitbutton"> Submit</button>

</div>
```

Also change in your controller

```
class SearchController extends Controller { 

  public function index()
  {
    $posts = Post::get();
    return view('Pages.search', compact('posts'));
  }
```

Comment: not what i was looking for as the data appears in the drop down menus, however when i click submit, the data is not showing on my screen. How do i link the submit button to my code ?

Comment: but how would i exactly get the data to display when i click submit. ATM its not doing anything

Answer (score 1):

```
 use App\Post;

public function index()
        {
            $posts = Post::latest()->get();
            return view('search',compact('posts'));
        }
@foreach($posts as $post)
  <option value="{{$post->id}}">{{$post->title}} </option>
 @endforeach
```